# Using mdadm to create RAID1 mirror warns "Fail create" but completes successfully

Tags: mdadm

When I create an `mdadm` RAID 1 array the command completes successfully but I get a warning.

System characteristics (Debian/Raspbian "bullseye" on a Pi 3):

```
uname -a
Linux pi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

mdadm --version
mdadm - v4.1 - 2018-10-01

head -n4 /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
```

Worked example:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=128 >/tmp/r1.img               # 128MB will do nicely
cp /tmp/r1.img /tmp/r2.img                                 # Another slice
for r in 1 2; do losetup /dev/loop$r /tmp/r$r.img; done    # Associate block devices

mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=raid1 --raid-devices=2 --metadata=default /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2
```

Warning message:

```
mdadm: Fail create md0 when using /sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

Exit status (`$?`) is zero, i.e. successful completion.

Status check (`cat /proc/mdstat`) after a few moments, having allowed the new RAID array to synchronise:

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 loop2[1] loop1[0]
      130048 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

The referenced "file" does exist:

```
ls -l /sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Sep 13 10:34 /sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array
```

Here's what seems to be the relevant segment from running `strace mdadm …`:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/mdadm/creating-md0", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_LARGEFILE, 0600) = 4
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array", O_WRONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
write(4, "md0", 3)                      = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
close(4)                                = 0
write(2, "mdadm: Fail create md0 when usin"..., 74mdadm: Fail create md0 when using /sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array
) = 74
unlink("/run/mdadm/creating-md0")       = 0
```

Given that the metadevice has been successfully created, what does the terminology `Fail create` mean in this context?

Comment: Which mdadm and kernel versions are you using? If new_array fails, it will fall back to old method, so it can still succeed (more recent mdadm adds this to the error message). However I'm not sure why this would fail in a reasonably current environment... [mdadm 1a8749301](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/mdadm/mdadm.git/commit/?id=1a87493014050e3bd94000cd36122c3cadf21270) [mdadm 039df3623](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/mdadm/mdadm.git/commit/?id=039df36231335fabe4da1a22fa3accb160d8bc1b)

Comment: You could check whether /sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array exists at all and/or strace mdadm creation process.

Comment: @frostschutz thanks for taking a look. I've added system details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally the `md_mod/parameters/new_array` parameter only supported creation of `"md_*" where * is not all digits`. Creation of `mdNNN` arrays was added later in [linux commit 039b7225e6](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=039b7225e6e98783a7a7e79c52b29c437f29967d), [mdadm commit 039df36231](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/mdadm/mdadm.git/commit/?id=039df36231335fabe4da1a22fa3accb160d8bc1b).

Although this commit predates your kernel, it never made it into v4.9.x, so your kernel does not support it yet. For this change to work, you need linux kernel v4.12 or newer, and mdadm v4.1 or newer. You already have mdadm v4.1, but the kernel is not updated, so this entire issue comes down to "your mdadm is newer than your kernel".

In this case `mdadm` falls back to old node creation mode, which works as intended so it's successful despite the error message. You still get your array in the end and all is well (it would probably fail for larger numbers or more exotic md names).

The question is why your bullseye kernel is so old at all. From what I see on raspbian, it should ship with linux 6.1 or 5.10, so not sure why you're stuck with 4.9.

Comment: That's really helpful thank you. I can't get my bullseye even to offer a newer kernel. Very strange. I'm currently looking at upgrading to bookworm so maybe that'll bring in a new kernel